# Node.js v8 HOLEY arrays unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, v8

After watching [Mathias Bynens](https://v8project.blogspot.com/2017/09/elements-kinds-in-v8.html) report about HOLEY and PACKED arrays, I did some experiments and got unexpected behavior. See two cases:

```js
// CASE #1
const array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,undefined]
array.__proto__[6] = 'some value'

console.log(array[6]) // "some value" expected but got undefined
```

```js
// CASE #2
const array = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
array[10] = 'faraway value'
array.__proto__[6] = 'some value'

console.log(array[6]) // "some value" expected and received
```

So, what the difference between these cases ? Why does in the first case it return `undefined` without looking in the prototype chain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case #1, you're explicitly putting `undefined` into the array. There is no need to go up the prototype chain because the element is present. Compare:

```
var case1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, undefined, 7];
var case2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, , 7];
case1.hasOwnProperty(6);  // true
case2.hasOwnProperty(6);  // false
console.log(case1[6]);  // "undefined", loaded from object
console.log(case2[6]);  // "undefined", because no element was found (not on the object, and not on the prototype chain)
case2.__proto__[6] = "proto value";
console.log(case2[6]);  // "proto_value", loaded from prototype chain
```

Comment: Yes, On the second case just console log the array. you will get `[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, <4 empty items>, 'faraway value' ]` But in the first array there is an element present `[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, undefined ]`

Comment: But, these <4 empty items> are technically  `undefined`. So, v8 optimizer also checks if it's an own property ?

Comment: @EnthusiasticDeveloper They are not technically `undefined`, they don't even exist.

Answer (score 0):

**What happens in your case 1**

```
const array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,undefined] //array length is 7
array.__proto__[6] = 'some value' //will not work becasue 6th position already exists and JS will not load it from proto chain

console.log(array[6]) // you will get undefined because you assigned undefined at 6th position
```

**In your case 2**

```
const array = [0,1,2,3,4,5] //length 6
array[10] = 'faraway value' //you added value on position 10, hence values between 6 and 10 is empty
array.__proto__[6] = 'some value' // you pushed value on position 6 using proto

console.log(array[6]) // you will get some value because position 6 is empty and hence JS tried to look into proto chain
```

So what basically you can say is, `__proto__` assignment will only work if the assigned position is empty, and hence if the position is empty then JS will lookup in the proto chain.

So,
if `array[6]` exists then `array.__proto__[6] = 'value'` will not work or change the value of existing `array[6]` value, but if `array[6]` is empty then doing `array.__proto__[6] = 'value'` and getting it will work

A side note, using `__proto__` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto).

Answer (score 0):

There's a distinction to be made between an undefined *key*, and an undefined *value*.

When you write `const array = [ 0, undefined ]` you are creating a two element array where the second index (1) has a *value* of undefined.

If instead you write `const array = [ 0, , ]` you are still creating a two element array but it is now *sparse* and the second index (or "key") doesn't even exist, even though it is less than the array's `.length` property.

Since there's no key, the interpreter will check in the prototype instead.